# Invalid schema configuration: `S` is not a valid type at path `0` mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i'm trying to create collection with schema in mongodb and expressjs
but showing this error:

Invalid schema configuration: `S` is not a valid type at path `0`. See  for a list of valid schema types.

what should we do?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    uname:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        minlength:[3,"minimum length of student name must be grather than  3 character ?"]
    },
    phone:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
        minlength:10,
        maxlength:10

    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
  
    },
    address:{
        type:String,
        required : true
    }
})

// here we create new collection
const StudentData = mongoose.Schema('Student',schema);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe, the below line is incorrect:

```
const StudentData = mongoose.Schema('Student',schema);
```

This should be the right syntax:

```
const StudentData = mongoose.model('Student',schema);
```